# HELP! Can't make glossary using taxonomy term name

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm using Drupal 8.0.2 and I'm trying to create a glossary of taxonomy terms by name. I have setup the view as follows:

- Unformatted list
- Fields: Taxonomy term: Name
- Filter: Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (= Fruit Name)
- Sort: Taxonomy term: Name (asc)

Stopping here the preview shows all Fruits by name (a-z) as expected.

Now when I add the following Contextual Filter:

- Taxonomy term: Name
- Type: Fixed
- Fixed value: a
- More: Glossary mode
- Character limit: 1

The preview is empty, and the page returns a 500 error. I have done this successfully many times using Content: Title, but it never works using Taxonomy: Name. Can anyone tell me why this won't work using taxonomies?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in D8 core. Here is a link to the issue:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2630692